# How to log output of apt-get upgrade to .txt file

Tags: apt, cron, logging, redirect

How do I log the output of `apt-get upgrade` to a `.txt` file? I read the man page and the `-q` option mentions formatting the output for logging.

The reason I am asking this question is because I would like to automate the update process.  Specifically I want to add `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y` to the root crontab. I want to log the output so I can view it later.

Also, could this cause any problems? Is it a bad idea to let the system upgrade packages without the user reviewing the changes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**These logs are already generated automatically.**

You can view the files in `/var/log/apt`.

There is a `history.log` which logs all executed `apt` commands, like this:

```
Start-Date: 2016-07-06  14:29:04
Commandline: apt upgrade
Requested-By: bytecommander (1000)
Upgrade: tzdata:amd64 (2016d-0ubuntu0.16.04, 2016f-0ubuntu0.16.04)
End-Date: 2016-07-06  14:29:06
```

The file `term.log` on the other hand logs the exact terminal output of those commands, like this:

```
Log started: 2016-07-06  14:29:04
(Reading database ... ^M(Reading database ... 5%^M(Reading database ... 10%^M(Reading database ... 15%^M(Reading database ... 20%^M(Reading database ... 25%^M(Reading database ... 30%^M(Reading database ... 35%^M(Reading database ... 40%^M(Reading database ... 45%^M(Reading database ... 50%^M(Reading database ... 55%^M(Reading database ... 60%^M(Reading database ... 65%^M(Reading database ... 70%^M(Reading database ... 75%^M(Reading database ... 80%^M(Reading database ... 85%^M(Reading database ... 90%^M(Reading database ... 95%^M(Reading database ... 100%^M(Reading database ... 302987 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../tzdata_2016f-0ubuntu0.16.04_all.deb ...
Unpacking tzdata (2016f-0ubuntu0.16.04) over (2016d-0ubuntu0.16.04) ...
Setting up tzdata (2016f-0ubuntu0.16.04) ...

Current default time zone: 'Europe/Berlin'
Local time is now:      Mi 6. Jul 14:29:06 CEST 2016.
Universal Time is now:  Wed Jul  6 12:29:06 UTC 2016.
Run 'dpkg-reconfigure tzdata' if you wish to change it.

Log ended: 2016-07-06  14:29:06
```

Please note that the logs get rotated automatically. Older logs get compressed and stored as e.g. `history.log.1.gz`.

---

However, if you want to manually log them, including the `apt update` command as well, you can use Bash's output redirection syntax:

```
( date && apt-get -q update && apt-get -qy upgrade ) &>> /var/log/apt/mylog
```

This redirects the output (both STDOUT and STDERR) of `date`, `apt-get -q update` and `apt-get -qy upgrade` and appends it to the file `/var/log/apt/mylog`. You may of course also pick a different file name and location.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It was very  thorough and informative.